# Changing complex computed object in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, javascript-objects, vue-component, computed-properties

I have complicated object for a table. Looks like this:

```
{
    1510002000: {
        date: "07.11.17"
        hours: {
            1510002000:{
                activity:{
                    activity: "Тест",
                    color: "#00ff00",
                    end_at: 1510005600,
                    start_at: 1510002000,
                    type_id: 1
                }
            },
            1510005600: {
                ...
            },
            ...
        }
    },
    ....
}
```

This is a code from template that uses this object:

```
    <tr v-for="date in this.tds">
        <td>{{ date.date }}</td>
        <td is="hour-td"
            v-for="hour in date.hours"
            :color="hour.activity.color"
            :start_at="hour.activity.start_at"
            :end_at="hour.activity.end_at"
            :activity="hour.activity.activity"
            :type_id="hour.activity.type_id"
        >
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I evaluated it as a computed property, but I need to rerender table when parent component provides data assync, so I have a watcher for prop (prop called "activities"):

```
watch: {
    activities: function(){
        var vm  = this;
        let dth = new DateTimeHelper;

        if (this.activities.length > 0){
            this.activities.forEach(function(activity){
                let dateTimestamp = dth.getDateTimestampFromTimestamp(activity.start_at); // just getting the key

                if (vm.tds[dateTimestamp]){
                    if (vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at]){
                        vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at].activity.activity = activity.activity;
                        vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at].activity.color    = activity.color;
                        vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at].activity.type_id  = activity.type_id;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        console.log(vm.tds) // here I can see that the object is filled with new data
    }
},
```

The problem is that the table doesn't rerender. More precisely, the component "hour-td" does not contain the new data.
Also I've tried to use Vue.set, but no success with that

Can you help me with the updating table? I've spent like 5 hours for refactoring and attempts.
Thanks in advance

SOLUTION
In my case there can be two states: there are activities, there are no activities. So I made two computed props for each case and render them separately and switch by v-if="activities.length"

Comment: It is difficult to get the big picture just from the code you have posted but I have worked with dates and computed properties before and Vue will not see a `Date` change as an update. Computed properties are cached and will only update if their dependencies updat,e so that is probably why your `hour-td` component is not working. The first thing I would try is to create a `new Date()` from the timestamp you have in your computed property.

Comment: Yes, you right about cache. But there is problem not with dates (it always in timestamp, so I work like with numbers, also they come from server) and not in cache (I use watcher, to rewrite cache). Here you can find full code of component https://github.com/Vasek18/my-hours.ru/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/hours-table.vue

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is with Vue known issue for `Change Detection Caveats` (you can read [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)) with array direct assignation, that don't detect changes.

You should change this part of code (with direct array assignation):

```
if (vm.tds[dateTimestamp]){
   if (vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at]){
      vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at].activity.activity = activity.activity;
      vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at].activity.color    = activity.color;
      vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at].activity.type_id  = activity.type_id;
   }
}
```

With the Vue.set() option for arrays in order to detect the change and re-renders the component. It worked for me in differents occassions:

```
// Vue.set(object, key, value)
// something like this: 
Vue.set(vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at].activity.activity,1,activity.activity);
```

More info here: https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/array-change-detection

Edit:

I see now that you said:

> Also I've tried to use Vue.set, but no success with that

What you mean with: "no success" ? Can you share the code? I have the same issue and I resolved with Vue.set..

You can also take a look to `vm.$forceUpdate()`, try to execute after the last console.log or grab all the code inside a `vm.$nextTick( [callback] )` in order to execute all the actions (load data in the table) and then, re-render the component on next tick.

More info here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate && https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick

Edit 2:

I think that your problem is with the index of the array, you should take a look here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection .
Try changing the:

```
if (vm.tds[dateTimestamp]){
                    if (vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at]){
                        vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at].activity.activity = activity.activity;
                        vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at].activity.color    = activity.color;
                        vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at].activity.type_id  = activity.type_id;
                    }
                }
```

and simplify with:

```
if (vm.tds[dateTimestamp] && vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at]){
   Vue.set( vm.tds, vm.tds.indexOf(vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at]), activity);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still cannot solve this problem. So I've tried "Vue.set(vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours[activity.start_at].activity, 'activity', activity.activity);" and "Vue.set(vm.tds, dateTimestamp, vm.tds[dateTimestamp]);" and "let temp = activity.start_at; Vue.set(vm.tds[dateTimestamp].hours, activity.start_at, {key: {activity: activity}});" in cycle. No result. Also try "this.$children.forEach(function(child){ child.$forceUpdate(); });". Also no success

Comment: Thanks for your help. This approach doesn't work, because it's not an array, but object, and because, how I understand, vue cannot make reactive an object in an object in an object. So I have another solution. Two separate props for the cases of existence of activities. You can see it here https://github.com/Vasek18/my-hours.ru/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/hours-table.vue

Comment: Ok! I'm glad you found the solution. Try to edit and response your own question in order to help someone in the future with the same problem! If the answer helped, upvote ;)